# cut and cuts subject verb agreement?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

As per the subject-verb agreement, if a subject is singular, its verb must also be singular

> He **sings**.

if a subject is plural, its verb must also be plural.

> They **sing**.

I have seen some examples of "cut" on the internet that created some confusion.

- Tom has **cut** his finger.
- Tom often **cuts** classes. `(Tom is singular - so cuts are used)`
- Tom **cut** classes again. `(why is cut used here and not cuts. Tom is singular)`
- My mother **cut** the cake.

  *(My mother is singular, then shouldn't we use cuts here)*
- This knife **cuts** well.

  *(knife is also singular)*
- Each cone **cuts** out an area on the surface equally inclined to the
  cone axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the distinction you made applies to the third person of the [present simple tense](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/present-simple-basic).

You have a mixed collection of different tenses in your examples:

- Tom **has cut** his finger - PRESENT PERFECT tense - cut is the [past particicle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/past%20participle). The same past particle is used for all subjects
- Tom often **cuts** classes - PRESENT SIMPLE tense
- Tom **cut** classes again and My mother cut the cake - PAST SIMPLE tense - the same word is used for all subjects

Your two last examples are PRESENT SIMPLE tense too, **cuts** applies to both of them because they use the third singular person: it.